# parsing xml with restKit

Tags: ios, xml, swift, parsing, restkit

I´m developing an app using `RestKit` and `Realm`.
Parsing JSON and save the object to the realm Database is no problem.

My Problem now is to parse xml and save this to the database.
I tried it with `RKXMLReaderSerialization` and `XMLReader`, but `XMLReader` ist too old because it is still using ARC.

Without of those two frameworks I#m getting this error:

```
NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got application/rss+xml}
```

How can I add `rss+xml`?

Edit:
I think I have to add `rss+xml` as a MIME-Type for RestKit, but how?

The Code below is my call to load my NewsFeed where I get the error message from above.

```
    static func loadNewsFromServer() {
        RKObjectManager.sharedManager().getObjectsAtPath(serverURL,
            parameters: nil,

            success: { (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, result: RKMappingResult!) -> Void in

                //handle sucess
            },

            failure: { (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                print(error)
            }
        )
    }
```

ResponseDescriptor:

```
let newsResponseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: News.restKitObjectMapping(), method: RKRequestMethod.GET, pathPattern: serveURL, keyPath: nil, statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClass.Successful))
```

Are there any possibilities to parse xml with restKit?

Many Thanks!

Comment: What about the default `NSXMLParser`?

Comment: I will get the error before parsing. I edited the question again

Answer (score 0):

You need to do: (provided in obj-c and swift, though I haven't checked the exact syntax and typed on an iPad...)

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"rss+xml"];

 RKMIMETypeSerialization.registerClass(RKXMLReaderSerialization.self, forMIMEType: "rss+xml")
```

And:

```
[myObjectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"rss+xml"];

myObjectManager.setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType("rss+xml")
```

Comment: I tried this solution allready, but if I'm importing `import RKXMLReaderSerialization` i will get the following error from xcode: `could not build Objective-C module RKXMLReaderSerialization` and I think this is because RKXMLReaderSerialization links to XML-Reader. But XML-Reader is last updated 5years ago and is still using ARC ...

Comment: So you'll need to find / create a different XML serialiser that you can use with `RKMIMETypeSerialization`. RestKit + XML + swift aren't going to have been used together much to date I guess...

Comment: actually I'm getting JSON for response :) Problem now is the responseDescriptor for the api with Requestparameter. Can you check my new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721011/restkit-get-request-with-queryparameter-no-matching-responsedescriptor